# Tabulator - Validate input after a new row is added

Tags: tabulator

Using Tabulator - Initially, when I build a table I can provide validation options in columns definition:

```
{title:"Rating", field:"rating", editor:"input", validator:"required"}
```

So, the cell in "Rating" column cannot be null. However, after I add a new row:

```
    $("#add-row").click(function () {
    table.addRow({});
});
```

, the validation functionality doesn not work for the "Rating" column in this newly created row. I can leave the cell empty and it will not complain.
Is there any way to preserve the columns structure including validating when adding a new row? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am late but maybe it helps someone else.

Tabulators validator is only run after user inputs data into the field. Not when a row is created.

If you don't want the field to be null, put some default value when creating the row -

```
$("#add-row").click(function () {
    table.addRow({"rating": "default_value"}); // Put default value
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple working solution:

```
tabulator.getTable().addRow({
    rating: null,
}, true).then(function( row ){
    row.validate();
});
```